# App store verification issues

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

I have an issue in IAP on app store. I have created consumable & non-consumable products in application.

After purchase I applied receipt verification  for purchased product.

Now I want to submit my application for review process & provide them a test User account, But issue is that  when I am going to submit my app, I have changed receipt verification 'URL' from **Sandbox** mode to **Distribution** Mode & I am providing them a sandbox mode user credential.

Now my issues is that if receipt verification url is changed then How IAP would be test on app store with Test User account credential.

Answer (score 2):

you always should use both sandbox and production URLs in your app. 
Verify your receipt first with the production URL. If it returns 21007 code, proceed with sandbox URL. 
Please see [FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html):

> 16 How do I verify my receipt (iOS)?
>   Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code. Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store.

Comment: Why? Only builds build with the Ad-Hoc or development profile require the sand URL. When you build for the AppStore there is no need to for the sandbox URL to be used.

Comment: +1 .This is the correct answer - your server should always verify first with the production URL - if you get 21007, fall back to the sandbox URL

Comment: rckoenes, I've added ref URL to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to provide an iTunes test account for Apple.

The only test account you must provide is an account that allows Apple to login in to your system. Like if I create an app that requires you to login in (like Facebook) then I will need to provide an account.